# Move a table in the HTML page

Tags: css, html-table, margin

Here is my CSS code of my table :

```
.styled-table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 25px 0;
 margin-top:10px 
    margin-left:100px
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    min-width: 400px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    top : 50px;
}

.styled-table thead tr {
    background-color: #009879;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: left;
}

.styled-table th,
.styled-table td {
    padding: 12px 15px;
}

.styled-table tbody tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.styled-table tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

.styled-table tbody tr:last-of-type {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #009879;
}

.styled-table tbody tr.active-row {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #009879;
}
```

I need this table somewhere in the centre of the page, and not at the top left corner, like how it is right now. I've tried adding margins, but they don't work. Please help.

Comment: You simply need to make the parent box of the table to be `display: flex` and use the `align-items: center; justify-content: center;` to center the table vertically and horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center any element both vertically and horizontally, Flexbox is your best option. [You can find a lot of guides online.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

In your case, you should define the container of your table as a Flex container that takes all the space of your page:

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr><td>Hello word</td></tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but I need only my table to be at the center

Comment: Could you provide the concerned part of your html?

Answer (score 0):

simply put your table to a div and use `flexbox` to align the table to the center

```html
<div>
      <table>
        <tr><td>your table</td></tr>
      </table>
</div>
```

```css
div{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: The heading (td) is getting detached from the table.